# VBA Solver Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined

Tags: excel, vba, reference, compiler-errors, solver

I am using office 365 for Mac, with version number 15.32.

I repeatedly get the "compile error: sub or function not defined" when I try to run the macro that is trying to implement a solver function, which was a previously recorded macro (so I know it is correct).  The error highlights the "SolverOk" part of the code.

I understand that this often occurs when the reference to Solver.xlam is not present, however I have no idea how to do this on the Mac if this is truly the issue.  Attached is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.  Does the Solver.xlam thing on the left indicates that it is there?  If so, do you have any idea what the problem is?

[Screenshot of available references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeU3t.png)

[Screenshot of error + VBA code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQV6o.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open File/Options/Add-Ins

On the page with the add ins, click on the bottom "Manage Excel Add-Ins" .. "Go..." and look for SOLVER related Add-ins there.

Once these are activated, return to VBA (Alt-F11) and then the "SOLVER" option should be available in Tools/References, where you want to Add it.